# edittext visible means how can i check the if condition in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, checkbox, android-edittext

I have checked my edittext is visible or invisible in android.

Now  i have to check the condition is.,

1. If my edittext is visible means how can i insert the data.
2. If my edittext is gone means how can i  insert on another data.

This is my code for if i have to check the checkbox means the edittext is invisible otherwise the edittext is visible  .:

```
 chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addresscheckbox);
        
    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
        {
             S_address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);  
             S_address.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
          
        Saddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);  
        Saddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
      }
        else
        {
             S_address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address1);  
             S_address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
          
       Saddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_address1);  
        Saddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(!(Saddress.getText().toString().length() == 0)){
            
                showAlertbox(" Shipping Address is Required!!"); 
            }
      }
```

The below code is ., if my edittext is visible means insert the saddr value.otherwise insert the baddr value.how can i check the condition.

Here below error is showing:
VISIBLE cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
      if(Saddress== VISIBLE)
    {
        PropertyInfo saddress =new PropertyInfo();
        saddress.setName("Saddress");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        saddress.setValue(saddr);//Define value for fname variable
        saddress.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(saddress);//Pass properties to the variable
        
    }
    else
    {
    PropertyInfo saddress =new PropertyInfo();
    saddress.setName("Saddress");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    saddress.setValue(baddr);//Define value for fname variable
    saddress.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(saddress);//Pass properties to the variable
    }
```

please see the full source code here:[full code](http://pastie.org/private/xrhcbfocjrpcjl5qgika)

**EDIT:**

In my code i have to check the checkbox means the Saddress is invisible know.that time i have to click the button means the baddr value is inserted...If i have to uncheck the checkbox means the Saddress value is visible.that time i have to insert the saddr value.

Here i have to run the app means the baddr value is insered both Saddress==visible and Saddess==invisible case.how can i write the condition for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
if(Saddress.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
  //.. your code here
}
```

instead of

```
if(Saddress== VISIBLE){
//.. your code here
}
```

because `VISIBLE`,`GONE` and `INVISIBLE` is part of View class instead of Activity

Comment: Hi i have checked the above code.but i have inserted the same value.but i have to insert the value visible means one data invible means another one data.please check the code and give me solution for these.these is my full source code:http://pastie.org/private/xrhcbfocjrpcjl5qgika

Comment: @android : ok let me check it

Comment: @android : can u plz make me clear about *but i have inserted the same value.but i have to insert the value visible means one data invible means another one data* line . what u exactly want

Comment: in my code i have to check the checkbox means the Saddress is invisible know.that time i have to click the button means the baddr value is inserted...If i have to uncheck the checkbox means the Saddress value is visible.that time i have to insert the saddr value.

Comment: @android : can i known where is issue i thing something logical mistake ?

Comment: i have to change the code like:if(Saddress.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        {
         PropertyInfo saddress =new PropertyInfo();
            saddress.setName("Saddress");
            saddress.setValue(baddr);
            saddress.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(saddress);
            
        }
        else
        {
        PropertyInfo saddress =new PropertyInfo();
        saddress.setName("Saddress");
        saddress.setValue(saddr);
        saddress.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(saddress);
        } means i got the o/p

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.getVisibility();
```

this will provide the edittext is VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE.

```
if(editText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
   //.. your actions are performed here
}
```

Refer [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29). You can find some interesting details about [VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) ,[GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) and [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)